# Can sharepoint 2010 search read a sitemap.xml for crawling?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, search

I need to set sitemap.xml for content source to search my files. is it possible to use xml file as my content source ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, SharePoint ignores sitemap.xml by default, and you don't have to use it. Instead make sure you have a crawl account that have read access to all content supposed to be crawled. In your content source you can define whether or not SharePoint should follow subsites and complex URLs.

Comment: like we are using website as source, we cant use xml files ?

Comment: @SharePointLearner Nope. If it's a SharePoint site, the Search Service Application already knows how the site/subsites are structured, and therefor site maps are ignored.

Comment: [link](https://blogs.realdolmen.com/experts/2013/03/20/enhance-seo-by-creating-your-dynamic-sitemap/)  is explaining about that topic but not much clear

Comment: @SharePointLearner I guess you're having your SharePoint Web App as a public website? If so the sitemap.xml will help external crawlers (Google, Bing, Yahoo, etc...) but doesn't effect the internal Crawling, Content Processing or Indexing.

Comment: yes i have a public web site and i have lots of pdfs file that i want to read that files from xml file for crawl . is there any other way ?

Comment: For internal search? No, and it's not needed either. SharePoint Search crawls PDF content (OCR) just as good.

Comment: how to add that sitemap.xml for external crawlers ?

Comment: On SharePoint  2013 this comes out of the box. Just enable the feature explained here http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/09/21/sharepoint-2013-site-collection-seo/

Comment: what to do for sharepoint 2010 ?

Comment: I think your first link holds the answer